# How to add GUI components to a container during runtime?

Tags: java, javafx

What I would like to do is to display different GUI containers in a given area based on onClick events. Here is a picture of what I'd like to achieve:
[image]

When clicking on the "Customers" button, id like to display new elements inside the big red square. I could technically lay them out and make them invisible and then visible during runtime, but there are 6 buttons each with it's own buttons that need to show different layouts so itll be alot of invisible layouts.

I am also interested in the best practices when trying to show/hide layouts inside an active GUI.

Comment: `TabPane` simply uses a `StackPane` containing the content of all tabs. It does indeed set the `visible` properties of all the children according to the selected tab. This has the benefit of all the tab contents contributing to the calculation of the size of the scene. If you don't do this or do not implement your own size calculation this would otherwise make a scenario possible, where the initially selected tab is very small and later on the selection of another tab the size of the control is not sufficent for the content...

Comment: @fabian I had difficulty understanding what you mean. Do you mean to replace the left nav bar with a tabpane?

Comment: Not necessarily. I just described a way of implementing something very similar in the core API. If using a `TabPane` works for you (adding a `VBox` with an `ImageView` and a `Label` as `graphic` to the `Tab`s and assigning `LEFT` to the `TabPane.side` property), sure, go ahead and use it; it provides a ton of functionality that will take some time to implement/maintain. Otherwise it's still a solid implementation that you could "draw inspiration from".

Comment: @fabian I actually figured out how to do that. You just load an FXML in the container that is pained in red. Should I post that as an answer?